# MySQL UNION COUNT

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, union

First let me show my tables data and then I will explain my problem.

**MySQL Tables Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE more_tags (
tag_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
more_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
tag_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
UNIQUE KEY (more_id, user_id, tag_name)
);

CREATE TABLE tags(
tag_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
another_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
tag_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (tag_id),
UNIQUE KEY (another_id, user_id, tag_name)
);
```

**more_tads table data**

```
tag_id  tag_name
10      apple 
192     apple 
197     apple 
203     apple 
207     apple 
217     news 
190     bff
196     cape
```

**tags table data**

```
tag_id  tag_name
1       apple 
2       time 
3       bff
```

Okay I asked a some what similar question earlier. But now for some reason I can't get the query to count the tags from both tables it only counts the tags from one table as in the example below

**Current Ouput**

```
tag_id  tag_name    num
1       apple       5
2       bff         1
3       cape        1
4       time        1
```

But I want to GROUP all similar tags and count how many times they where found in the tables as in the example below

**Desired Output**

```
tag_id  tag_name    num
1       apple       6
2       bff         2
3       cape        1
4       time        1
```

**Current MySQL QUERY**

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT `more_tags`.`tag_id`, `more_tags`.`tag_name`, COUNT(`more_tags`.`tag_name`) as 'num' 
FROM `more_tags` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `more_tags`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`active` IS NULL 
AND `users`.`deletion` = '0' 
GROUP BY `more_tags`.`tag_name`
UNION(
SELECT `tags`.`tag_id`, `tags`.`tag_name`, COUNT(`tags`.`tag_name`) as 'num' 
FROM `tags` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `tags`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`active` IS NULL 
AND `users`.`deletion` = '0' 
GROUP BY `tags`.`tag_name`))
AS table_1 
GROUP BY `tag_name`  
ORDER BY `tag_name` ASC
```

Comment: Can you try after removing `()` for 2nd brackets ?

Comment: @Bhavik Shah, Nothing still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The tag_id in your desired output doesn't really make sense to me. Without that here is how you get what you are asking:

```
SELECT tag_name, SUM(num)
FROM(SELECT `more_tags`.`tag_name`, COUNT(*) as 'num' 
FROM `more_tags` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `more_tags`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`active` IS NULL 
AND `users`.`deletion` = '0' 
GROUP BY `more_tags`.`tag_name`
UNION ALL
SELECT `tags`.`tag_name`, COUNT(*) as 'num' 
FROM `tags` 
INNER JOIN `users` ON `tags`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`active` IS NULL 
AND `users`.`deletion` = '0' 
GROUP BY `tags`.`tag_name`)
AS table_1 
GROUP BY `tag_name`  
ORDER BY `tag_name` ASC
```

SQL Fiddle with the user logic removed to demonstrate the key point: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea44d/2

Also Don't forget the UNION **ALL** and **SUM** which are the key parts missing in your question. Without UNION ALL you could have some rows rejected as duplicates when they are not in an example like the one I gave in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This will output the results you want. Just add the user joins in the Sub queries.

```
SELECT a.tag_id, a.tag_name, SUM(a.num)
FROM (
     SELECT tag_id, tag_name, SUM(1) as num  FROM tags
        GROUP BY tag_name
     UNION
     SELECT tag_id, tag_name, SUM(1) as num  FROM more_tags
        GROUP BY tag_name
      ) a
GROUP BY a.tag_name
```